# PHP contact form not sending to email

Tags: php, forms

Here's the PHP I think its all correct but it won't send the form to the email on it

```
    $emailSubject = 'Rayykz has recruited a channel!';
    $email_to = 'support@breeze-studios.com';

/* Gathering Data Variables */


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Username:$username
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .="Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($email_to, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

And here is the form connected to it

```
<form action="rayykz.php" method="post" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input name="name" class="form-control" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Username</label>
                  <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" value="" id="username">
                  <p class="help-block">Example "BreezeYTube".</p>               
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Channel</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Form</button>
              </form>
```

The form does not send to the email address, can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Could be any number of things.  You need to provide us more details, what value does $success have after calling mail()?  Have you looked at your mail sending software's logs to see if it processed and sent the message?  Do you know for sure the email address is correct and isn't blacklisting the mail you're sending as spam?

Comment: I have other forms on the server and they all work correctly its just this one, it also says its sent on $theresults

Comment: Your code checks out, I tested it with no problem. @OfficiallyFrex

Comment: I did add and wrapped the PHP in a `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` conditional statement, then I named the submit button to `name="submit"` which worked for me. @OfficiallyFrex

Comment: A time ago i had problems with a host server sending emails with name different than username. If the code works fine in other circunstances as you said, review the mailserver parameters.